# Redirect to another page if DropzoneJS image upload is success with php variable

Tags: php, redirect, dropzone.js

I am using dropzoneJS in my form. The form also record user input. Below code shows what I am doing in simple. Everything is working fine but php variable is not getting its value. It is somewhat like this

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
 $imgID = submitData()//This functions upload image and write image url in database and then return ID of the affected row
}
```

When submit button in form is clicked, redirection is happening but $imgID is not getting its value

Here is the Javascript

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
 autoProcessQueue: false,
 etc.. etc ..
init: function() {
 var myDropzone = this;
 $("#submit-all").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   if (myDropzone.files.length) {
    myDropzone.processQueue(); // upload files and submit the form
    } else {
    $('#my-awesome-dropzone').submit(); // submit the form
    }
  });
// Refresh page when all images are uploaded
myDropzone.on("complete", function (file) {
     if (myDropzone.getUploadingFiles().length === 0 && myDropzone.getQueuedFiles().length === 0) {
          var idvar = '<?php $imgID; ?>';
    window.location.replace("/preview.php?id="+ idvar);
    }
  });
 }
}
```

Suggest me where I am doing wrong. Is there any alternative available.

Comment: PHP loads before the page loads and only at that point. You will never be able to get the image ID dynamically like that. You will have to reload the page or make an AJAX call.

Comment: can you show example please. I am not expert in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the id back to the browser as response and take it with dropzone on success event like this.

php: (If this file is used to handle other requests a possible structure can be like this)

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' && !empty($_FILES)) 
{
    $imgID = submitData();
    echo $imgID;
}
else
{
    // The rest of your php file shoul go in here.
}
```

js:

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {

    // .........

    init: function() {
        // ........

        // On success refresh
        this.on("success", function (file) {
            var idvar = $.trim(file.xhr.response);
            window.location.replace("/preview.php?id=" + idvar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not working. In browser's console the error is showing - `Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined`

Comment: @Bips What version of dropzone are you using? I changed the answer to get the response directly from the file object.

Comment: Now `var idvar` is getting its value but some other content/text are trailing in the url, for e.g. mywebsite/preview.php?id=1<script type etc.....etc.. <html>...and goes long...
I am using latest version of dropzoneJS

Comment: @Bips well, then now the problem is in the php file, because the trailing text is being printed in the php file. Either you should simply use a separated file to handle the upload with only the code that prints the id, or structure the file with other conditions to only execute the code that prints the id when a file is uploaded. I can add an example of this later approach if you need.

Comment: ok, can you please show me _the other condition to only execute the code that prints the id when a file is uploaded_ This will help me lots