# Spring POST redirect + dropzone.js

Tags: spring, redirect, post, dropzone.js

I have got an issue with redirection after handling POST request.

Dropzone.js sends an POST request that contains all uploaded files. I am intercepting that request with method called handleFileUpload

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") List<MultipartFile> files,
                                         @RequestParam("comment") Boolean comment,
                                         @RequestParam("naming") Boolean naming,
                                         @RequestParam("newLine") Boolean newLine,
                                         @RequestParam("styleWeight") Integer styleWeight,
                                         @RequestParam("quantity") Integer quantity)
```

So far it works well. Files are visible, I do some things to them and then the problem appears. After doing magic I would like to **redirect** into another page (open it), called **result.html**

I have tried the following way:

```
...method
 return "result.html";
```

Of course that would be too easy. Then I read about *redirect* clause and tried another way:

```
return "redirect:/result.html";
```

Still no luck. However I have noticed in Chrome console that after using the redirect clause there was actually a **GET request** that fetched *result.html* page and it returned **code 200** so page the was found but it was not opened.

So the question appears: how to actually open a new page after handling POST request? It is the only way that Dropzone.js can send files into my server so I can' get rid of POST request. Most desirable output of my program would be:

- send files via POST (done)
- receive files in Controller class (done)
- do some magic (done)
- put the result into some model so I can display POJOs [actually just a five integers] in result.html page (not done but I think I can figure it out)
- open result.html page

Most earlier questions regarding this topic forward to *redirect* clause but it does not work as you can see.

Comment: Dropzone uses ajax to send the form, so if you want to redirect to another page when the upload is done, you should do it by configuring dropzone in the javascript. Yo should include your dropzone configuration in the question to allow people to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: @wallek876 Dropzone itself has little configuration required. There is a button on website that calls upload() method. This method calls `dropzone.processQueue()` and that's all. I thought about putting redirection here but I would like to open the page **after** doing magic with uploaded code, not before. It takes about 3-4 seconds and redirection in JS would be instant.

Comment: You should use the dropzone `success` event, . see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532240/redirect-to-another-page-if-dropzonejs-image-upload-is-success-with-php-variable